# JavaScript this.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

Я читал подобные пробелмы и вопросы, но в моем контексте он немного отличается. Попробую описать максимально точно и детально
Есть js файл, который отвечает за работу с меню. В меню всего два пункта: удалить файл, переименовать файл. у них нет id, есть атрибуты delete, edit

```
window.addEventListener('load', changeMenu);

function changeMenu() {
  // добавляет listener каждому элементу в списке файлов и папок
  // получаю все элементы списка
  let files = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDown");

  // добавляю событие на правый клик мыши для каждого элемента
  for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i ++){
    files[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", showEditMenu);
  }

  // спрятать меню
  document.addEventListener("click", hideEditMenu);
}

function showEditMenu(e) {
  // функция показывает меню с опциями
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // получаю имя файла, который AJAX - ом отправлю на сервер
  let fileName = e.target.getAttribute("data-fileName");
  // действия для отрисовки меню
  let menu = document.getElementById("editMenu");

  let top = e.pageY;
  let left = e.pageX;

  menu.style.cssText = 'display: block;' + 'top: '+ top + 'px; left: ' + left  + 'px;';
  // получаю список вариантов и добавляю каждому listener по клику на него - нужно определить какая опция выбрана (удалить файл. переименовать файл)
  let options = document.querySelectorAll("#editMenu ul li a");
  for(let i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    options[i].addEventListener('click', sendRequest);
  }
}

function sendRequest(e) {
  // и вот тут проблема. Не могу передать переменную fileName в эту функцию, вообще никак! 
  // перенос этой функции внутрь функции showEditMen не предлагать.
  let actionName = e.target.getAttribute("data-option");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
options[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) { sendRequest(e, fileName); });

function sendRequest(e, fileName) {
  // ...
}
```